# In a module, know which component asks informations

Tags: magento2, module

collaborating to Lillik/PriceDecimal project, I'm stuck on a detail:  how can I know which page/module et calling my function ?

For now, I'm using a global variable

```
    $Val = $this->getConfig()->getPricePrecision(); 
    $Val =  (strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'checkout') > -1 ) ? $this->getConfig()->getPricePrecisionCheckout() :  $Val;
```

I want to replace the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] by the proper Magento's object.

I can I do that?

Thanks for reading and for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the Magento official devdocs
[image]
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/security-performance-data-bp.html#use-wrappers-instead-of-superglobal-variables